# How to split 'title' and 'icon' in Bootstrap panels?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, accordion, panel

I am adding a FAQ section on my website (not live yet so no link). I have some minor CSS problems i cannot solve. I have a panel that looks like this:

[image]

**Problem #1:**
- There is no dividing the icon and the text (see image). The title can be long and short.
- The icon is not centered when Title is long and have multiple rows(lines), the icon just goes down. (see image)

How can i both divide the Title into 2 parts where the 1 part in centered on height and width(icon). Thanks

```css
.btn,
    .btn:hover,
    .btn:focus,
    .btn:active,
    .btn:active:focus {
        outline: 0;
    }

    .btn-custom {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }

    .no-margin {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .no-padding {
        padding: 0;
    }

    .no-border {
        border: 0;
    }

    .no-radius {
        border-radius: 0;
    }


    /*** Content ***/
    main {}

    .i-row {
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }

    .i-row-odd {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    .i-row-even {
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
    }

    .section-title {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0.6em;
        font-weight: 500;
    }

    .section-title .fa {
        margin-right: 5px;
        color: #6f5499;
    }


    .i-accordion .panel-heading,
    .d-accordion .panel-heading,
    .accordion-2a .panel-heading,
    .accordion-2b .panel-heading,
    .accordion-3 .panel-heading {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .d-accordion .panel-heading.collapsed .fa-chevron-up:before {
        content: '\f078';
    }


    .panel-success>.panel-heading {
        background-color: transparent;
        border-color: transparent;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel-group i-accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".i-accordion" href="#aboutus3">
                <h4 class="panel-title">test<i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-left"></i></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="aboutus3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>answer</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".i-accordion" href="#whoweare3">
                <h4 class="panel-title">testtesttesttesttesttest<i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-left"></i></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="whoweare3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>answer</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".i-accordion" href="#contactus3">
                <h4 class="panel-title">testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttestesttes ttesttestt<i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-left"></i></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="contactus3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>answer</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".i-accordion" href="#cold">
                <h4 class="panel-title">test<i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-left"></i></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="cold" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>answer</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Updated Answer:**
[image]

The problem is now fixed, but some minor problem is still remaining:
 - The title and icon is now divided, but i need to have more space for icon.
 - The icon still goes down some px with title longer than 1 row/line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution using `flex`, move your `icon` before text and set

```
.panel-title{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center
}
```

```css
    .panel-title {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center
    }

    .panel-title > i {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    .btn,
    .btn:hover,
    .btn:focus,
    .btn:active,
    .btn:active:focus {
        outline: 0;
    }

    .btn-custom {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }

    .no-margin {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .no-padding {
        padding: 0;
    }

    .no-border {
        border: 0;
    }

    .no-radius {
        border-radius: 0;
    }


    /*** Content ***/
    main {}

    .i-row {
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }

    .i-row-odd {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    .i-row-even {
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
    }

    .section-title {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0.6em;
        font-weight: 500;
    }

    .section-title .fa {
        margin-right: 5px;
        color: #6f5499;
    }


    .i-accordion .panel-heading,
    .d-accordion .panel-heading,
    .accordion-2a .panel-heading,
    .accordion-2b .panel-heading,
    .accordion-3 .panel-heading {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .d-accordion .panel-heading.collapsed .fa-chevron-up:before {
        content: '\f078';
    }


    .panel-success>.panel-heading {
        background-color: transparent;
        border-color: transparent;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel-group i-accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".i-accordion" href="#aboutus3">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>test</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="aboutus3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>answer</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".i-accordion" href="#whoweare3">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>testtesttesttesttesttest</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="whoweare3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>answer</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".i-accordion" href="#contactus3">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttestesttes ttesttestt</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="contactus3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>answer</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".i-accordion" href="#cold">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>test</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="cold" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>answer</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great @Hai Pham. This works. Some minor problems if you could see the updated answer i added new image to show the problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @AliDurrani I have updated my answer with `margin-right: 10px` to the `icon`, check it out.

Comment: Awsome @HaiPham. Just like i wanted it :) Answer Accepted!